# LaTeX template for document to be submitted to SAP

Tags: templates

I am having a hard time formatting my paper for the following journal submission.
They don't supply any tex templates.

Can anyone assist me in formatting the first page at least?

This is the provided [MS Word template](http://www.sapub.org/global/download.aspx?filename=SAP-Manuscript-Template.doc)

Comment: Don't do that. If the journal doesn't give latex template but only word, they may expect word document at the end. You will be in trouble later.

Comment: As the editorial office if they'll take TeX submissions at all. If they will us a 'vanilla' document in the absence of a template (`article` and only packages you absolutely require).

Comment: The 6th item under the "Manuscript Submission Checklist" header at http://www.sapub.org/Journal/manuscriptsubmission.aspx reads as follows: "The submission file is in Microsoft Word document format only." The instructions also state that "submissions may be returned to authors that do not adhere to these guidelines." I'd interpret the term "may" as "almost certainly will"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Edited to arrange the template in two files and to provide an addendum to show how one might use subfloats.)

Even though I fully agree with Harish's and Joseph's recommendations *not to use LaTeX for the conference/journal version of your paper* -- at least not until you've gotten an explicit go-ahead from the conference organizers and/or journal editors that it's OK to use LaTeX -- I couldn't resist coming up with the following template.

The template comes in two parts: The first file, named `SAPtemplate.sty`, is a LaTeX style file. It uses other LaTeX packages, macros, and environments to avoid, as much as possible, having to clutter up the document with visual formatting instructions. The second file, named `SAPtemplate.tex`, uses the LaTeX style file to typeset the contents of the MS Word template file. (Well, the two figures are different, as explained below.) In your own document, be sure to use either the `article` or the `scrartcl` document class and to set the global font size option to `10pt`.

Because the MS Word instructions say that figures and tables should always be placed as close as possible to their first call-outs, I've provided an environment called `SAPmp` (short for "SAP minipage", I suppose) that is based on a LaTeX "`minipage`" (which doesn't float). I suggest you replace all current `figure` and `table` environments with `SAPmp` environments, and use `\captionof{figure}{...}` and `\captionof{table}{...}` directives to generate the captions. Note that these environments can be cross-referenced using the usual `\label`-`\ref` mechanism.

You've raised a follow-up question, on how to handle subfloats (given that no "floats" -- in the LaTeX sense of the word -- are used). I would suggest you use `minipage` environments inside the `SAPmp` environments to handle such cases. The file `SAPtemplate.tex` has modified the two figures to show how you might go about arranging sub-graphs either horizontally or vertically.

Incidentally, I can't help but remark that the MS-Word based template contains a glaring inconsistency with regard to the formatting the authors' names in the bibliography: in the first ten entries, the first-name initials come *before* the surnames, but in the final eight entries the ordering is reversed. In the body of instructions, one finds the requirement that first-name initials should come before the surnames. Finally, I've also edited the contents of Table 1 of the template to strike out two instructions that are just wrong in view of the remainder of instructions given in the template.

The following screenshot shows the upper two thirds of the second page of the template. Note the horizontally arranged graphs and captions in Figure 1 and the vertically arranged graphs and captions in Figure 2; they are meant to function as practical examples of how you might handle subgraphs in your own document.

[image]

File 1: "SAPtemplate.sty"

```
%%% SAPtemplate.sty
%%%
%%% Implement the SAP formatting instructions, as given 
%%% under the "Manuscript Template" header at 
%%% http://www.sapub.org/Journal/manuscriptsubmission.aspx
%%%
%%% Mico Loretan, August 2015
%%%
%%% Note: The LaTeX document that loads this template 
%%% should use "10pt" as the main font size.


%% Dimensions of text block
\usepackage[a4paper,vmargin=15mm,left=20mm,right=15mm]{geometry}

%% Font: Times Roman, for both text and math
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

%% Two-column layout
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\columnsep{4.4mm} % space between columns

%% Formatting of figure and table captions
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{dotspacespace}{\textbf{.}\space\space}
\captionsetup{labelsep=dotspacespace,labelfont=bf,
              size=footnotesize,skip=6pt}

%% Formatted minipages to house figures and tables
%% ("SAPmp" is short for "SAP-minipage")
\newenvironment{SAPmp}{%
     \bigskip
     \noindent
     \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
     \footnotesize % switch to 8pt font size
     }{%
     \end{minipage}
     \medskip}

%% Citation call-outs and references
\usepackage{cite}% or: \usepackage[numbers,square]{natbib}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{\small}

%% Format *text* of sectioning headers
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\rmfamily\fontsize{14}{17}\selectfont\raggedright}
\subsectionfont{\rmfamily\raggedright\normalsize}
\subsubsectionfont{\rmfamily\raggedright\normalsize\mdseries}

%% Format *counters* of sectioning headers
\makeatletter
%% The "@seccntformat" command is an auxiliary command
%% (see pp. 26f. of 'The LaTeX Companion,' 2nd. ed.)
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
    {\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}    % default
    {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}} % individual control
\newcommand{\section@cntformat}{\thesection.\space}
\newcommand{\subsection@cntformat}{\thesubsection.\space}
\newcommand{\subsubsection@cntformat}{\thesubsubsection.\space}
\makeatother

%% Compact formatting of itemized and enumerated lists
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep}

%% Indent first lines of all paragraphs
\usepackage{indentfirst}  


%% Macros for title, author, abstract, keywords, and author affiliations
\newcommand\SAPtitle[1]{{\fontsize{20}{25}\selectfont
   \centering\bfseries#1\par}}

\newcommand\SAPauthor[1]{\bigskip\bigskip
   {\fontsize{11}{13.5}\selectfont\centering#1\par}}

\newcommand\SAPabstract{%
   \bigskip
   \hrule
   \bigskip\medskip\noindent
   \textbf{\large Abstract}\space\space}

\newcommand\SAPkeywords{%
   \bigskip\noindent
   \textbf{\large Keywords}\space\space}

\newenvironment{SAPaffil}{
   \bigskip
   \begin{center}
   \small % switch to 9pt font size
   \begin{tabular}{c}}{%
   \end{tabular}
   \end{center}}

%% Use ordinary (Roman) lettering for URL strings
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\urlstyle{same} 

%% No page numbering
\pagenumbering{gobble}

%% Miscellaneous
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\frenchspacing  % no extra space after punctuation marks
\raggedbottom
```

File 2: "SAPtemplate.tex"

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} 

\usepackage{SAPtemplate}

% Load all other packages you may need for your document,
% e.g, "amsmath", "tikz", "booktabs", etc

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove "demo" option in real document
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % "\sout" used in Table 1

%% Code for Table 1 of this document
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}


\begin{document}

\SAPtitle{Type the Title of This Paper, Capitalize First Letter of Each Content Word}

\SAPauthor{\textbf{First Author}\textsuperscript{1},
           \textbf{Second Author}\textsuperscript{2},
           \textbf{Third Author}\textsuperscript{3}}

\begin{SAPaffil}
  \textsuperscript{1}Department Name of Organization, Name of Organization, City, Postcode, Country (first author's affiliation)\\
  \textsuperscript{2}Department Name of Organization, Name of Organization, City, Postcode, Country (second author's affiliation)\\
  \textsuperscript{3}Department Name of Organization, Name of Organization, City, Postcode, Country (third author's affiliation)\\
\end{SAPaffil}

\SAPabstract This document gives formatting instructions for authors preparing papers for publication in SAP. The authors must follow the instructions given in the document for the papers to be published. You can use this document as both an instruction set and as a template into which you can type your own text. The body of abstract immediately follows abstract heading in the same paragraph. For example, this paragraph begins with abstract heading.

\SAPkeywords Include at least 3 keywords or phrases, must be separated by commas to distinguish them.

\bigskip\medskip
\hrule
\bigskip


%% Very little visual formatting is needed from here on out

\begin{multicols*}{2}

\section{Introduction}

This template, created in MS Word 2003 and saved as ``Word 2003---doc'' for the PC, provides authors with most of the formatting specifications needed for preparing electronic versions of their papers. All standard paper components have been specified for three reasons: 1) ease of use when formatting individual papers, 2) automatic compliance to electronic requirements that facilitate the concurrent or later production of electronic products, and 3) Margins, column widths, line spacing, and type styles are built-in; examples of the type styles are provided throughout this document. Some components, such as multi-leveled equations, graphics, and tables are not prescribed, although the various table text styles are provided. The formatter will need to create these components, incorporating the applicable criteria that follow. Use the styles, fonts and point sizes as defined in this template, but do not change or redefine them in any way as this will lead to unpredictable results. You will not need to remember shortcut keys. Just a mouse-click at one of the menu options will give you the style that you want.


\section{Page Layout}

An easy way to comply with the paper formatting requirements of SAP is to use this document as a template and simply type your text into it.

Your paper must use a page size corresponding to A4 which is 210mm wide and 285mm long. The margins must be set as follows:
\begin{itemize}
\item Top = 15mm 
\item Bottom = 15mm 
\item Left = 20mm
\item Right = 15mm
\end{itemize}

Your paper must be in two-column format with a space of 4.4mm between the columns.


\subsection{The Paper Should Have the Following Structure}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Title of the paper
\item Authors and affiliations 
\item Abstract (at least 100 words)
\item Keywords 
\item Introduction - including motivation, aims (and for long papers structure of the paper), overview and references to related work (in separate section)
\item Main body - explanation of methods, algorithms, data used, instrumentation (sensors, systems, etc.), results and discussion
\item Conclusions
\item References
\end{enumerate}
Your goal is to adhere to this paper in appearance as closely as possible. 


\section{Page Style}

All paragraphs must be indented. All paragraphs must use justified alignment. With justified alignment, both sides of the paragraph are straight.


\subsection{Text Font of Entire Document}

The entire document should be in Times New Roman. The font sizes to be used are specified in Table~\ref{tab:1}. 

The size of a lower-case ``j'' will give the point size by measuring the distance from the top of an ascender to the bottom of a descender.


\subsection{Title and Author Details}

All title and author details must be in single-column format and must be centered.

Every word in a title must be capitalized except for short minor words such as ``a'', ``an'', ``and'', ``as'', ``at'', ``by'', ``for'', ``from'', ``if'', ``in'', ``into'', ``on'', ``or'', ``of'', ``the'', ``to'', and ``with''.

Author details must not show any professional title (e.g. Managing Director), any academic title (e.g. Dr.) or any membership of any professional organization (e.g. Senior Member IEEE).

To avoid confusion, the family name must be written as the last part of each author name (e.g. John A. K. Smith).

Each affiliation must include, at the very least, the name of the company and the name of the country where the author is based (e.g. Causal Productions Pty Ltd, Australia). An email address is mandatory for the corresponding author.


\begin{SAPmp}
\captionof{table}{Font Specifications for A4 Papers}
\label{tab:1}
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{|c|C|C|}
\hline
Font & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Appearance (in Times New Roman or Times)}\\
\cline{2-3}
Size & Regular & Bold\\
\hline
8 & table caption, centered & \\
  & figure caption, centered  & \\ 
  & material in tables and figures & \\
\hline
9 & reference items & \\
  & Author's affiliation, centered & \\
  & \sout{Table heading, centered} & \\
\hline
10 & Paragraph & level-2 headings, left-justified\\
  & abstract body & \sout{author affiliation, centered}\\
  & keynotes body & \\
  & level-3 headings, left-justified & \\
\hline
11 &  & author name(s), centered\\
\hline
12 &  & abstract heading\\
   &  & keynotes heading\\
\hline
14 &  & level-1 headings, left-justified\\
   &  & acknowledgement heading\\
   &  & reference heading\\
\hline
20 &  & Paper title, centered\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{SAPmp}


\subsection{Section Headings}

No more than 3 levels of headings should be used. Headings must be in 10pt font except Level-1 Headings. Every word in a heading must be capitalized except for short minor words.

Level-1 Heading: A Level-1 heading must be left-justified and numbered with an Arabic numeral followed by a period. For example, see heading ``3. Page Style'' of this document. The two Level-1 headings which must not be numbered are ``Acknowledgment'' and ``References''.

Level-2 Heading: A Level-2 heading must be left-justified and numbered with an Arabic numeral followed by a period. For example, see heading ``3.3. Section Headings'' above.

Level-3 Heading: A Level-3 heading must be numbered with an Arabic numeral followed by a period. The body of the level-3 section immediately follows the level-3 heading in the different paragraph. 


\subsection{Figures and Tables}

Graphs and other numbered figures should appear throughout the text as close to their mention as possible. Figures shouldn't infringe upon the page borders.

Figures and tables must be centered in the column. Large figures and table can be in one column in order to see them more clearly and avoid placing them in the middle of columns. Any table or figure that takes up more than 1 column width must be positioned either at the top or at the bottom of the page. ``Figure. 1'' should be used, even at the beginning of a sentence.

\begin{SAPmp} 
% Two horizontally arranged subgraphs
\begin{minipage}{0.475\columnwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{test.pdf}
\centering (a) First subfigure
\end{minipage}\hspace{\fill}
\begin{minipage}{0.475\columnwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{test.pdf}
\centering (b) Second subfigure
\end{minipage}
\captionof{figure}{A sample line graph using colors which contrast well both on screen and on a black-and-white hard copy}
\label{fig:1}
\end{SAPmp}


\subsubsection{Figure Captions}

Figures must be numbered using Arabic numerals. Figure captions must be in 8 pt Regular font. Captions of a single line (e.g. Figure~\ref{fig:2}) must be centered whereas multi-line captions must be justified (e.g. Figure~\ref{fig:1}). Captions with figure numbers must be placed after their associated figures, as shown in Figure~\ref{fig:1}.

\begin{SAPmp}
% Two vertically arranged subgraphs
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.6\columnwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,
                 height=0.45\columnwidth]{test.pdf}

\end{minipage}

\smallskip
(a) First subfigure

\medskip
\begin{minipage}{0.6\columnwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,
                 height=0.45\columnwidth]{test.pdf}

\end{minipage}

\smallskip
(b) Second subfigure

\bigskip

\captionof{figure}{Example of an image with acceptable resolution}
\label{fig:2}
\end{SAPmp}


\subsubsection{Table Captions}

Tables must be numbered using Arabic numerals. Table captions must be centered and in 8pt Regular font. Every word in a table caption must be capitalized. Captions with table numbers must be placed before their associated tables, as shown in Table~\ref{tab:1}.


\subsection{Links and Bookmarks}

All hypertext links and section bookmarks will be removed from papers during the processing of papers for publication. If you need to refer to an Internet email address or URL in your paper, you must type out the address or URL fully in Regular font.


\subsection{Equations}

Equations should be numbered consecutively throughout the paper. The equation number is enclosed in parentheses and placed flush right, as in \eqref{eq:1}. Your equation should be typed using the Times New Roman font (please no other font). To create multileveled equations, it may be necessary to treat the equation as a graphic and insert it into the text after your paper is styled.
\begin{equation} \label{eq:1}
\{\varepsilon\}_e=[B]\{\delta\}_e
\end{equation}


\section{References}

The heading of the References section must not be numbered. All reference items must be in 9 pt font. Please use Regular styles to distinguish different fields as shown in the References section. Number the reference items consecutively in square brackets (e.g. \cite{metev-veiko:1998}). References should be cited in the text and listed in the reference section. Refer simply to the reference number, as in \cite{zzsm:1999}---do not use ``Ref. [3]'' or ``reference [3]'' Capitalize only the first word in a paper title, except for proper nouns and element symbols.


\section{Conclusion}

The version of this template is V1. Most of the format-ting instructions in this document have been compiled by SAP Productions. SAP Productions offers A4 templates for Microsoft Word. SAP Productions has tried its best efforts to ensure that the templates have the same appearance.

SAP Productions permits the distribution and revision of these templates on the condition that SAP Productions is credited in the revised template as follows: ``original version of this template was provided by courtesy of SAP Productions''.


\section*{Acknowledgment}  % note use of "starred" version of macro

The heading of the Acknowledgment section and the References section must not be numbered.

SAP Productions wishes to acknowledge all the contributors for developing and maintaining this template.


\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{metev-veiko:1998}S. M. Metev and V. P. Veiko, Laser Assisted Microtechnology, 2nd ed., R. M. Osgood, Jr., Ed. Berlin, Germany: Springer-Verlag, 1998.

\bibitem{breckling:1989}J. Breckling, Ed., The Analysis of Directional Time Series: Applications to Wind Speed and Direction, ser. Lecture Notes in Statistics. Berlin, Germany: Springer, 1989, vol. 61.

\bibitem{zzsm:1999}S. Zhang, C. Zhu, J. K. O. Sin, and P. K. T. Mok, ``A novel ultrathin elevated channel low-temperature poly-Si TFT,'' IEEE Electron Device Lett., vol. 20, pp. 569--571, Nov. 1999.

\bibitem{wwog:2000}M. Wegmuller, J. P. von der Weid, P. Oberson, and N. Gisin, ``High resolution fiber distributed measurements with coherent OFDR,'' in Proc. ECOC'00, 2000, paper 11.3.4, p. 109.

\bibitem{srv:1997}R. E. Sorace, V. S. Reinhardt, and S. A. Vaughn, ``High-speed digital-to-RF converter,'' U.S. Patent 5 668 842, Sept. 16, 1997.

\bibitem{shell:2002}M. Shell. (2002) IEEEtran homepage on CTAN. [Online]. Available: \newline \url{http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/supported/IEEEtran/}

\bibitem{flexchip:1996}FLEXChip Signal Processor (MC68175/D), Motorola, 1996.

\bibitem{shell:2002}``PDCA12-70 data sheet,'' Opto Speed SA, Mezzovico, Switzerland.

\bibitem{karnik:1999}A. Karnik, ``Performance of TCP congestion control with rate feedback: TCP/ABR and rate adaptive TCP/IP,'' M. Eng. thesis, Indian Institute of Science, Bangalore, India, Jan. 1999.

\bibitem{pft:1999}J. Padhye, V. Firoiu, and D. Towsley, ``A stochastic model of TCP Reno congestion avoidance and control,'' Univ. of Massachusetts, Amherst, MA, CMPSCI Tech. Rep. 99-02, 1999.

\bibitem{mr:1960}Matlock, H., and Reese, L.C., 1960, Generalized solutions for laterally loaded piles., Journal of Soil Mechanics and Foundation, 86(5), 63--91.

\bibitem{nz:1972}Nayak, G. C., and Zienkiewicz, O. C., 1972, Convenient forms of stress invariants for plasticity, Proc. ASCE, 98(4), 949-953.

\bibitem{nvg:1995}Noorzaei, J., Viladkar, M. N., Godbole, P. N., 1995, Influence of strain hardening on soil-structure interaction of framed structures, Computers \& Structures, 55(5), 789-795.

\bibitem{oh:1980}Owen, D. R. J., and Hinton, E., 1980, Finite elements in plasticity-theory and practice, Pineridge Press, Swansea.

\bibitem{pise:1982}Pise, P. J., 1982, Laterally loaded piles in a two-layer soil system., J. Geotech. Engrg. Div., 108(9), 1177--1181.

\bibitem{poulos:1971}Poulos, H. G., 1971, Behavior of laterally loaded piles--I: Single piles, J. Soil Mech. and Found. Div., 97(5), 711--731.

\bibitem{rm:1956}Reese, L. C., and Matlock, H., 1956, Non-dimensional solutions for laterally loaded piles with soil modulus assumed proportional to depth., Proc., 8th Texas Conf. on Soil Mechanics and Foundation Engineering, Austin, Texas, 1--23

\bibitem{rw:1975}Reese, L. C., and Welch, R. C., 1975, Lateral loading of deep foundations in stiff clay., J. Geotech. Engrg. Div., 101(7), 633--649.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\bigskip\noindent\textbf{\large Keywords}\quad`? you make me sad :(

Comment: @SeanAllred - I was tired yesterday evening and decided to give it a rest. :-) I've updated the code in the meantime to further reduce the need for visual formatting.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for the help! works great.. One question though, how do I allow subfloats in the SAPmp? It's giving error, no outer par

Comment: @Syntax_Error - Glad this has been helpful. Regarding your follow-up question: I've modified my answer to show how one can go about handling subgraphs even though "subfloats" (in the LateX sense of the word) can't be used.